# Permissions denied for directory - c++

Tags: c++, permissions, directory

I'm trying to build ogre newton application from svn.
I have win7 && vs 2008.
There is **inc** directory which is included into resources (additional include directories).

But after compiling I get error:

> fatal error C1083: Cannot open source
>   file: '*\newton20\inc': Permission
>   denied    c1xx

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the compiler is trying to open the **inc** directory as a source file.